# Where can I find the network log on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a simple GCE Instance and I just lost the external IP allocated to it. I'm the only admin and the external IP just vanished after a server halt and all sites that I have there simply stop to work...

I have to reserve another external IP, change the DNS for every website but this operation was very stressful.

Is there a log on Google Cloud where I can see what happened?

And is there any strategy to have a failsafe for this glitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use the [VPC Flow logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/flow-logs) for network monitoring:**

> VPC Flow Logs records a sample of network flows sent from and received
> by VM instances, including instances used as GKE nodes. These logs can
> be used for network monitoring, forensics, real-time security
> analysis, and expense optimization.

Linked documentation describes how to enable it and set up.

**You can furhter improve monitoring if you enable [logging for firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewall-rules-logging)** (you have to do it individually for each one).

About this "dissapearing IP" - just [reserve an external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) for your instance - if this happens again you can report an issue at [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) but you could also try to look into some logs inside your VM (here's a very usefull site about [logs in Linux](https://www.eurovps.com/blog/important-linux-log-files-you-must-be-monitoring/)) that may be helpful for you.

You may also try to [view your activity logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/activity-logs) (or ["classic" logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview)) for your instance in StackDriver to put even more light in what happened and why your reservded IP dissapeared.

Comment: Did my answer helped you in any way ? If so I'd appreciate if you upvoted it or accepted.